# Change the default flask behavior for a form field that doesn't exist

Tags: python, flask

When using the flask `request` object, attempting access a form arg that doesn't exists - i.e.

```
request.args['keyThatDoesntExist']
```

will result in a

```
"Bad Request, 400" error coming back to the client browser.
```

This design bothers me because it results in a very opaque error that doesn't give a line number where the issue happened or anything else to debug.  I don't want to use request.args.get('keyThatDoesntExist') because I like to get an error rather than a default value when the key doesn't exist.  That is, I like to know when something is wrong rather than chugging along with mysterious behavior.

Is there any way to change the behavior so a `KeyError` is raised at that line rather than a `Bad Request` coming back?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `app.config['TRAP_BAD_REQUEST_ERRORS'] = True` - in that case those errors will be handled like a real error.

However, you should consider why Flask handles those KeyErrors specially: If a user sends you crap, it's not an error in your application. So why should it fail with an internal server error and possibly an error reporting email (remember, in production you won't have the flask debugger running, and in debug mode you get a proper error anyway).